# Know the class of a mouseenter link in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, children

I have a little problem with jquery children.

I have this code :

```
<li><a href="#" class="gocinema">cinema</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="gomusic">music</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="gogame">game</a></li>
```

I try to set up a function for changing the color of the link on hover. (I cannot simply do that with css because, it's for a complex webdesign on a menu.)

What i try to do is to make a function who said :

> What is the class of the link i am mousenter ?
>
> If the class is that, do  that. If the class is that, do that.

I have a read a lot of article on jquery children, but i don't fin how to say that in a function.

Sorry if it's not very clear :/
Thanks

Thomas

Comment: you can use `.attr('class')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'a', function () {

    if ( this.className === 'gocinema' ) {
        // do this
    }

    if ( this.className === 'gomusic' ) {
        // do that
    }

});
```

**Update**

If there's more than one class on your link, you could try `$.fn.hasClass`:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'a', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ( $this.hasClass('gocinema') ) {
        // do this
    }

    if ( $this.hasClass('gomusic') ) {
        // do that
    }

});
```

Comment: You are welcome! If your question is answered, mark it as it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').mouseenter(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('class'));
   var classes = $(this).attr('class');
   if(classes == 'whatyouwant'){
      //do something
   }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SV3Km/)

Answer (score 0):

If its menu, This should be proper way to do it with jquery.

HTML

```
<ul class="mymenu">
  <li><a href="#" class="gocinema">cinema</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="gomusic">music</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="gogame">game</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('.mymenu a').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover-style');
}, function () {
      $(this).removeClass('hover-style');
});
```

CSS

```
.hover-style{
    background:red;
    color:white
}
```

Check the live demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/ruchit47/HGbrQ/

---

Additionally
If you want to give different style to each menu item.
You can create styles this way.

```
.hover-style.gocinema{ background:red; } 
.hover-style.gomusic{ background:blue; } 
.hover-style.gogame{ background:green; }
```